# Node.js having error when handling large concurrent requests

Tags: node.js, load-testing

I'm running a load test on a very simple NodeJS application which implements a REST API designed to respond with the contents of a JSON file (67kb).

I'm using `loadtest` to test it. However, half of the requests are emitting errors and I can't find the cause. Any ideas? Thanks.

Load Test:

```
loadtest -n 5000 -c 1000 http://localhost:8082/hello
```

[Load Test Result Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qjxpb.png)

Source:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const fs = require('fs');

app.get('/hello', (req, res) => {
fs.readFile(`${__dirname}/data.json`, function(err, data) {
    if(err){
        console.log(err);
    }

    console.log('Received a request.');
    res.send(data.toString());
    });
})

app.listen(8082, () => {
    console.log('Server is started. Port: 8082')
});
```

Comment: What are the errors?  It seems possible your server might not support 1000 concurrent requests without further tuning of the IP stack.

Comment: You can find 2991 errors at the bottom but I can't find any in error logs. I am only using my laptop as server. So, I need to configure sth in my laptop first? Thanks.

Comment: Also, `fs.readFile()` uses a very small thread pool to do its work so you'd be limited in actual concurrency to the size of that thread pool which would slow things down.  Did you try if you just `res.send("Hello")` with no `fs.readFile()`?  FYI, the thread pool size can be increased, though I don't know if that's your bottleneck or not.

Comment: Knowing what the error was might help.  The loadtest doc indicates that a `-r` parameter might produce a report with all the error codes.  If you're exceeding the TCP queue size for incoming connections on your laptop, that might be indicated by the particular error.

Comment: FYI, this an old article so you probably need to find a newer resource for explicit settings in modern Windows, but if you read this you'll get an idea about the types of tuning that affect how many concurrent connections you can be running: http://smallvoid.com/article/winnt-tcpip-max-limit.html

Comment: More reading: https://forums.whirlpool.net.au/archive/2687929 - Windows artificially limits concurrent TCP connections in desktop OS (they want you to buy Windows server).

Comment: @jfriend00 After I changed to res.send("Hello"), still having errors.

Comment: Then, it's probably your laptop that isn't able to handle 1000 simultaneous requests.  Windows desktop operating systems are dumbed down in that capability to make you buy Windows server for actual servers.  If you read those other articles I've linked for you, they explain.